# Delegates - how to?

Tags: java, android, function, interface, callback

I'm trying to use interfaces in my android java project. Callback interfaces seems to be the answer to C# delegates, but I can't get my head around it, I've read other similar questions, but again, I can't get it to fit my needs or get it to work. What I need is to call a function in Class A that is pass as a parameter to Class B. When class B finishes a task, returns the result to A by calling the function previously saved in a variable:

```
class A {

   B myBClass;

   public A() {
       myBClass = new B();
       myBClass.doSomething(ResultFunction);
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }

   public void ResultFunction(<result parameters>) {
       //do something with the result from the task in myBClass
   }

}

class B {

    Function myCallback;

    public B() {

    }

    public void doSomething(ResultFunction) {
        myCallback = callback;
        //does something
        SomethingFinished();
    }

    private void SomethingFinished() {
        myCallback.call(<result of doSomething>);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can't you just make method `doSomething` from `ClassB` return the results so you can call your own method from A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

**1) Use anonymous class:**

Remove `ResultFunction` argument from `doSomething` method in class `B`

And reimplement it in class `A`

```
   public A() {
       myBClass = new B() {
            @Override
            public void doSomething() {
                super.doSomething();
                //do here what you need what you want to do in B class
            }
       }
       myBClass.doSomething();
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }
```

**2) Use`Callable` interface**

```
interface Callable {
    public void call();
}
```

pass it instead of `ResultFunction`

```
class A {

   B myBClass;
   Callable callable = new Callable {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            //do here what you need what you want to do in B class
        }
   }

   public A() {
       myBClass = new B();
       myBClass.doSomething(callable);
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }

}

class B {

    Callable myCallback;

    public B() {

    }

    public void doSomething(Callable callable) {
        myCallback = callable;
        //does something
        SomethingFinished();
    }

    private void SomethingFinished() {
        myCallback.call();
    }

 }
```

With lambdas it can look like a bit better

```
   public A() {
       myBClass = new B();
       myBClass.doSomething(()->{
          //do here what you need what you want to do in B class
       });
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why can't you just do the following:

```java
public class A {

   private B myBClass;

   public A() {
       myBClass = new B();
       Result result = myBClass.doSomething();
       resultFunction(result)
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }

   public void resultFunction(Result result) {
       //do something with the result from the task in myBClass
   }

}

public class B {

    public B() {

    }

    public Result doSomething() {
        //does something
    }
 }
```

If, for whatever reason, you must do that, you can do it easily in Java 8 like this:

```java
public class A {

   B myBClass;

   public A() {
       myBClass = new B();
       myBClass.doSomething(A::resultFunction);
       //Continue doing other tasks
   }

   public void resultFunction(Result result) {
       //do something with the result from the task in myBClass
   }

}

public class B {

    private Consumer<Result> myCallback;

    public B() {

    }

    public void doSomething(Consumer<Result> callback) {
        myCallback = callback;
        //does something
        myCallback.accept(result);
    }

 }
```